# Why tkinter fails on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter

I was using tkinter on Mac. But when I used the following simple code, the computer will restart.

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
```

What is the problem? Thank you!

- Mac: Mojave, version 10.14.6
- tkinter: version 8.6
- python:  3.7.3

Comment: @Shark Deng Seems to be like common problem https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/#built-in-8-6-8 according to them >If you are using macOS 10.6 or later, the Apple-supplied Tcl/Tk 8.5 has serious bugs that can cause application crashes. You might want to reinstall python https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-374/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be like common problem [python.org/download/mac/tcltk/#built-in-8-6-8](http://python.org/download/mac/tcltk/#built-in-8-6-8) according to them

> If you are using macOS 10.6 or later, the Apple-supplied Tcl/Tk 8.5 has serious bugs that can cause application crashes.

Rather than fixing TCL/TK I recommend you to want to reinstall a python version that satisfies the requirement & use it [python.org/downloads/release/python-374](http://python.org/downloads/release/python-374)

Comment: hi could I know what version of python finally worked? I am having similar issue with tkinter on my Mac

Comment: Hi @PrasKam it was 3.7.X.

Comment: thanks mate, I upgraded my OS to 10.15.4 and that fixed the bug as well