# What version of python 3 is compatible with tkinter

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, macos-mojave

6.10 on my Mac Mojave 10.14.6

and looks like running tkinter crashed/ restarts my Mac

The question is already been asked (see the link below) 
[Why tkinter fails on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57505107/why-tkinter-fails-on-mac)

Does anyone know what version of python is compatible with tkinter

for those who are interested I just ran a simple code

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

def printtheword():
    print('Success!')

b1 = Button(window,text="Execute",command=km_to_miles)
b1.grid(row=0,column=0)

e1 = Entry(window)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)

t1 = Text(window,height=1,width=20)
t1.grid(row=0,column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: All versions of Python should be compatible with Tkinter. If this is crashing your machine you have bigger problems. When it _doesn't_ crash your machine, do you see any output in the terminal? Any error messages?

Comment: Though, what does "6.10" refer to? That's not a Python version...

Comment: well there is definitely some Mac specific issue if you look at the link provided. I think it works fine with any version on windows. Sorry I meant 3.6.10 (python version)

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded my Mac OS to Catalina 10.15.4 and the problem is fixed!